# How to share a screenshot?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to share the screenshot of the app on Twitter, Facebook, etc. This is my code: it saves the picture, but doesn't open the share media task. I know the problem is in the path :{

```
var wb = new WriteableBitmap(LayoutRoot, new TranslateTransform());
using (var mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary()) {
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
    var fileName = string.Format("{0}.jpg", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss"));
    wb.SaveJpeg(stream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    mediaLibrary.SavePicture(fileName, stream);
    shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();
    shareMediaTask.FilePath = fileName;
    shareMediaTask.Show();
  }
}
```

How can I get the saved picture's path?

Isn't it possible to just simply take a screenshot and share it without saving it on the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the real path for the MediaLibrary file, you'll need to use the [GetPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.medialibraryextensions.getpath(v=xnagamestudio.42).aspx) extension method, something like;

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions;

...

var picture = mediaLibrary.SavePicture(fileName, stream);
shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();
shareMediaTask.FilePath = picture.GetPath();
shareMediaTask.Show();
```

Comment: Ooo .. so this way a person can read all the images in the library and send it to a server! I was thinking that the user intentionally should choose a picture by `tasks`

Comment: @Shi I've never tried accessing the filename one gets back without giving it to the ShareMediaTask, so not sure if you have permission to read it without requesting permission.

Comment: getting photo,music and video permission is not too hard. thanks @Joachim it worked, But I think I should check permissions of all the apps on my phone too :(

Answer (score 0):

For sharing the screen shot it is not required to save the image , in windows 8.1 it is very easy.

Here is the code, enjoy!

```
async void dataTransferMgr_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            DataRequest request = args.Request;
            request.Data.Properties.Title = "Title";
            request.Data.Properties.Description = "brief description";
            request.Data.SetText("detailed information");


            RandomAccessStreamReference imageStreamRef = await ScreenshotToStreamReferenceAsync(yourChartControlName);
            request.Data.Properties.Thumbnail = imageStreamRef;
            request.Data.SetBitmap(imageStreamRef);

        }

private async Task ScreenshotToStreamAsync(FrameworkElement element, IRandomAccessStream stream)
{
var renderTargetBitmap = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(element);

var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

var dpi = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;

var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
encoder.SetPixelData(
BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
(uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
(uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
dpi,
dpi,
pixelBuffer.ToArray());

await encoder.FlushAsync();
}

private async Task<RandomAccessStreamReference> ScreenshotToStreamReferenceAsync(FrameworkElement element)
{
var ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await ScreenshotToStreamAsync(element, ms);
ms.Seek(0);
return RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(ms);
}
```